# Defining an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, filter

I am new to VBA and am seeking advice. I would like to filter the array, copy the data and paste it onto a new sheet. This is the array, in which the left column is the company name, and the other columns are the delivery IDs.

```
Tim hortons 1100    2100    3100    4100    5100    6100    7100
mcdonalds   1101    2101    3101    4101    5101    6101    7101
mcdonalds   1102    2102    3102    4102    5102    6102    7102
mcdonalds   1103    2103    3103    4103    5103    6103    7103
mcdonalds   1104    2104    3104    4104    5104    6104    7104
A&w         1200    2200    3200    4200    5200    6200    7200
A&w         1201    2201    3201    4201    5201    6201    7201
A&w         1202    2202    3202    4202    5202    6202    7202
A&w         1203    2203    3203    4203    5203    6203    7203
Five guys   1204    2204    3204    4204    5204    6204    7204
```

How can I define my array without having to type out all the associated delivery IDs?

I have tried to define my array by typing out all the associated delivery IDs

- this is a snippet of my code -

```
' DEFINE ARRAYS
Tim  hortons = Array("1100", "2100", "3100", "4100", "5100", "6100", "7100")
mcdonalds = Array("1101", "2101", "3101", "4101", "5101", "6101", "7101", _
                     "1102", "2102", "3102", "4102", "5102", "6102", "7102", _
                     "1103", "2103", "3103", "4103", "5103", "6103", "7103", _
                     "1104", "2104", "3104", "4104", "5104", "6104", "7104")
etc.
```

Comment: Store the data in a range and read the array from the range?

Comment: Try to load text (csv) file with Power Query.

Comment: If you're not going to type the data, how *do* you expect the computer to know what it is?  Is it already being stored somewhere that you can access programmatically?

Comment: it is already being stored in table format. I am having trouble writing the VBA code to identify the company name and the delivery IDs associated with it.

Comment: Why do you even need VBA for that? Wouldn't lookup formulae suffice?

Comment: With Microsoft 365, you could use something like `=TOCOL(FILTER(B2:H11,A2:A11=K1),1)` if the result should be the IDs spilled in a single column and cell `K1` would hold the company name to match. If that's not what you're looking for, add more detail i.e. explain what you're planning to do with those arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need this in a labelled array format, but if you do, you can use a dictionary where the `Key` is the name of the array and the `item` is the array itself.

In the below, I used an [`ArrayList`](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/) object as it is simpler to collect the data (and you can then sort or re-order it if you want).

```
Option Explicit
Sub createArrays()
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim AL As Object
    Dim I As Long, j As Long, v As Variant
    
'many ways to detect the data table
'may need to change this depending on your
'worksheet setup

vSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    
'create dictionary so as to have "named" arrays
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        With AL
            For j = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
                AL.Add (vSrc(I, j))
            Next j
        End With
    If Not dict.Exists(vSrc(I, 1)) Then
        dict.Add Key:=vSrc(I, 1), Item:=AL
    Else
        For Each v In AL
            dict(vSrc(I, 1)).Insert dict(vSrc(I, 1)).Count, v
        Next v
    End If
Next I
        
'Change to arrays
For Each v In dict
    dict(v) = dict(v).toarray
Next v

End Sub
```

***Output for mcdonalds***
[image]